# How to list what is installed in a linux distribution that is using microdnf as package manager?

Tags: redhat-containers

I'm trying to create an image based on https://hub.docker.com/r/redhat/ubi9-minimal which has microdnf as its package manager.

I noted that after I installed python3 on it, some more packages was installed other than its direct dependencies.

I want to  investigate, but strangely microdnf doesn't have a `list` command as dfn or yum has. :)

```
Usage:
  microdnf [OPTION…] COMMAND

Commands:
  upgrade              Upgrade packages
  update               Compatibility alias for the "upgrade" command
  module reset         Reset a module stream
  distro-sync          Upgrade/downgrade packages to match versions in repositories
  dsync                Compatibility alias for the "distro-sync" command
  remove               Remove packages
  reinstall            Reinstall packages
  clean                Remove cached data
  repolist             List repositories
  module enable        Enable a module stream
  download             Download packages
  makecache            Generate the metadata cache
  module disable       Disable a module stream
  repoquery            Search for packages matching keyword
  install              Install packages
```

How can I know what is installed on such distribution that is using microdnf ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've discovered that the *ubi9-minimal* base image has the *rpm* tool.

So, to list the installed packages on it, just type `rpm -qa`